# Why can't I assign an array of hashes in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a problem with defining an array of hashes in ruby. I found some solution, but none of them answered what's wrong with this little sample of code:

```
users = [{:id => "1", :imie => "Szymon", :punkty => "0"}, 
{:id => "2", :imie => "Krzysiek", :punkty => "0"}, 
{:id => "3", :imie => "Przemek", :punkty => "0"}, 
{:id => "4", :imie => "Paweł", :punkty => "0"}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What error or problem are you seeing? That is valid syntax for me on Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Works on OS X in ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Couldn't the problem be in encoding? Try to remove ł in `Paweł`.

Comment: It's ruby.rb:4: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)
ruby.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}'
          {:id => "4", :imie => "Paweł", :punkty => "0"}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue with - `:imie => "Paweł"` this entry. **invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)**

use like this:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
users = [{:id => "1", :imie => "Szymon", :punkty => "0"}, 
{:id => "2", :imie => "Krzysiek", :punkty => "0"}, 
{:id => "3", :imie => "Przemek", :punkty => "0"}, 
{:id => "4", :imie => "Paweł", :punkty => "0"}]

p users.class #=>Array
```

use the below:

```
Encoding.default_external = 'utf-8'
Encoding.default_internal = 'utf-8'
```

Comment: thank you. as far as I use # encoding: UTF-8 in pure ruby it works, but doesn't work with sinatra.

Comment: I added #encoding line before all the requires and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: My pleasure! :) enjoy your programming. accept it as answer.

Comment: @Priti - You know the one first time you answered my question your reputation was 80. By the time I'd confirmed your answer your reputation was 160. And now 437.....You reputation is flying.

Comment: @PratikBothra so,are you happy? :)

Comment: Oh ya, I am happy. I am more or less done with my project. That conversion to params format was quite necessary to use someone's api. Everything else went smoothly enough. How come you are here so often? Just ran into free time, or suddenly decided to contribute?

Comment: @PratikBothra Good question! I love ruby in one sentence. But never did any project only home practice,but looking for a job on this.I am working as an Oracle resource.